# Reducing multiple api calls from client to backend PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a notifications table that is referencing the likes table. Currently, I am calling multiple API calls to create rows in the two tables from the client side.

For example: If a user likes a post, it creates a row in the likes table and it also creates a row in the notifications table.

And when a user deletes the like again it calls for two API calls to delete both rows from the two tables.

Since the only unique column, I have on the likes table is the id (auto-increment primary key), I was trying to figure out what would be the most efficient way to go about it as I can use on delete cascade for deleting part but when it comes to inserting, I wasn't sure whether to use a trigger to create the row in notifications table every time user likes or if there is another way going about it?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to when talking about API calls; 1) Two separate REST API requests? or 2) Two queries is the backend code? You will need to add to your question a code example of what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I advise caution with this approach.

If you are implementing application logic with triggers, it will be invisible further up the stack. This could cause maintainability problems down the line.

If you have some way of version controlling the database configuration (including trigger definition) and have this integrated into a deployment pipeline then maybe it won't be so bad.

However, I argue that this is what APIs are *for*. They are the natural place for application logic to sit. They are readily version controlled and very flexible.

There are a couple of ways to play it:

1. can you make both database calls from the same API? Instead of having a separate API for notifications, have an API for likes (that supports POST and DELETE methods to like/unlike). This API would use a single database transaction to update the likes *and* notifications table (ensuring they stay synced)
2. if the two APIs must remain separate, can you create a second API layer? A front-of-house API for likes could (asynchronously?) make calls to the 'core' likes API and to the notifications API. There are fewer guarantees with this approach but it does reduce you to one client-side API call, as required.